# Get properties of one object from the list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects and then I want to find one object and display value of property with ID.

```
Names name1 = new Names(){ID=1, User="John"};
Names name2 = new Names(){ID=2, User="Mike"};
Names name3 = new Names(){ID=3, User="Ben"};
```

This is list these objects below:

```
List<Names> names;
```

Now I would like to return name of the User with ID equals 2. What inquiry I have to use when I have only list of objects?

Comment: Side note, `Names` is plural, that reads a little odd. Better to use singular for your objects, ie `Name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Names name1 = new Names() { ID = 1, User = "John" };
Names name2 = new Names() { ID = 2, User = "Mike" };
Names name3 = new Names() { ID = 3, User = "Ben" };

List<Names> names = new List<Names>();
names.Add(name1);
names.Add(name2);
names.Add(name3);
```

To find `object` with `id=2`

```
Names obj = names.Where(x => x.ID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
int ID = obj.ID;
string UserName = obj.User;
```

Answer (score 6):

You do it using one of `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` dependng on your requirements,

I suspect the most appropriate is `SingeOrDefault` based on the fact an ID is usually unique, so you only ever expect one single item with a specified `ID`

```
var item = names.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 2);
if(item != null){
    var name = item.Name;
}
```

The difference between `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` is that the former will thrw an error if not found, the latter will return the default value - `null` in the case of an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not aware of the LINQ and then try this

```
Names name1 = new Names() { ID = 1, User = "John" };
Names name2 = new Names() { ID = 2, User = "Mike" };
Names name3 = new Names() { ID = 3, User = "Ben" };

List<Names> names = new List<Names>();
names.Add(name1);
names.Add(name2);
names.Add(name3);

foreach(var item in names)
{
  if(item.ID == 2)
  {
     string strName = item.Name;
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: at least break out of the loop when you've found it!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will return a list containing all names which are against user ID for example 1,
// or an empty list if there is no user with ID 1

var allnames = names.Where(u => u.ID == 1).ToList();
```